# Alternating linear forms: are they in direct sum with symmetric linear form?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $E$ a $\mathbb R-$vector spaces of dimension $n$. We say that $f$ is $p-$alternating if $$f(x_1,...,x_p)=0,\quad (x_1,...,x_p)\in E^p$$
whenever $x_i=x_j$ for some $i\neq j$ (and $p\leq n$). Since $\mathbb R$ has a characteristic $\neq 2$ this is equivalent to $$f(x_{\sigma 1},...,x_{\sigma p})=\varepsilon(\sigma )f(x_1,...,x_p)$$
for all $\sigma \in \mathfrak S_p$. And such linear form are called "antisymmetric". I know that with matrices, the set of matrices are in direct sum with symmetric and antisymmetric matrices, i.e. $$\mathcal M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)=\mathcal S_n\oplus \mathcal A_n.$$

**Question :** If I denote $\mathcal L_p(E)$ the space of linear form $E\to \mathbb R$, $\Lambda _p(E)$ the space of $p-$linear form and $\mathcal S_p(E)$ the space of symmetric linear form, does it hold that $$\mathcal L_p(E)=\Lambda _p(E)\oplus \mathcal S_p(E) \ \ ?$$

---

**Attempts**

The thing is I don't find any theorem that says that. If $f\in \mathcal L_p(E)$, then if I denote $$f_{ij}(x_1,...,x_i,...,x_j,...,x_p)=f(x_1,...,x_j,...,x_i,...,x_p)$$
$$f(x_1,...,x_p)=\underbrace{\frac{f+f_{ij}}{2}}_{:=g}+\underbrace{\frac{f-f_{ij}}{2}}_{:=h}\tag{*}$$
then $g$ is symmetric and $h$ antisymmetric. So 
$$\mathcal L_p(E)=\Lambda _p(E)+\mathcal S_p(E) $$
looks true. But the the writing $(*)$ looks far to be unic, so I have big doubt that the sum is direct. Also, I tried : let $f\in \mathcal S_p(E)\cap \Lambda _p(E) $.
Then $f(x_1,...,x_p)=f_{ij}=-f_{ij}$ anf thus $$2f_{ij}=0\implies f_{ij}=0,$$
therefore $f=0$. So it looks to be a direct sum. Since I've never sen such a result, I have doubt that my argument is correct.

Comment: Can you give some examples of an alternating and symmetric linear forms on a vector space of dimension $n>2$? You are using $n$ and $p$ in your question. Are you maybe talking about multilinear forms?

Comment: @Christoph: yes, multilinear form. For example, if $E=\mathbb R^3$, then $f(x,y)=x_1y_1$ is a $2-$multilinear form where $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$Your $f+f_{ij}$ and $f-f_{ij}$ are symmetric and anti-symmetric only with respect to the $i$-th and $j$-th argument. They are not symmetric and anti-symmetric as multilinear forms.

Note that the dimensions of $\mathcal L_p(\R^n)$, $\Lambda_p(\R^n)$ and $\mathcal S_p(\R^n)$ are $n^p$, $\binom{n}{p}$ and $\binom{n+p-1}{p}$, respectively. What does this say about your conjecture that $\mathcal L_p(\R^n)=\Lambda_p(\R^n)\oplus\mathcal S_p(\R^n)$?

Comment: Well see for the first part. Well, for the second part, I tried with some value, and it works... so I guess, this work :-) (but how would you right $f$ as a sum of symmetric and antisymmetric ?)

Comment: It works for $p=2$, try any $p>2$...